# Using ConvertTo-SecureString issues: Can I reset multiple ADUC passwords using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, server, directory

excuse me for my rusty understanding of programming, hoping someone could take a glance at this and see where my mistake is. I'm having issues trying to mass reset passwords within a test 2008 R2 domain using Powershell. I imported the AD module into Powershell. I have a .csv file containing the sAMAccountName (ADUC usernames) and I import that into powershell by assigning object $UserFile = "c:\2019StudentsB115.csv". Then I am using a foreach loop to go through and reset the passwords on each account but this is where it always seems to fail.

I tried adding the password to the .csv file as a 2nd column and that didn't work. Then I removed the 2nd column and removed the corresponding code for the passwords. I tried using ConvertTo-SecureString to give the generic password "Qwerty10" to all of these accounts. These accounts are all getting 1 generic password and I do not want the user to have to reset it upon first login. I thought I could use a foreach loop to easily do this but I get errors no matter what I do.

The code I've tried is as follows:

Attempt 1: Endless loop of error "Cannot bind argument to String because it is null"

```
foreach ($Account in $Resetpassword) {
    $Account.sAMAccountName
    $Account.Password
        Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $Account.sAMAccountName -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Account.Password -AsPlainText "Qwerty10" -force) -Reset
}
```

Attempt 2: Error "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null." lime:3 char:40

```
$UserFile = "c:\2019StudentsB115.csv"


foreach ($Account in $Resetpassword) {
    $Account.sAMAccountName
        Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $Account.sAMAccountName -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Qwerty19" -AsPlainText -force) -Reset
}
```

I thought maybe it was my syntax using `Set-AdAccountPassword` but then I tried this and it worked fine:  `Set-AdAccountPassword -Identity "math1-1" -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Qwerty10" -force)`

I'm passing the identity Math1-1 and the password Qwerty10 as a new password to this cmdlet and it works, so why can't I pass this using the .csv file? Any tips or pointers would be appreciated. I have about 20 tabs open from Googling this and nothing is really helping. I reviewed the syntax for Get/set ADAddcount and ConvertTo-SecureString but that isn't really helping me figure out how to assign objects from this .csv file.

Alex

I tried running:

```
foreach ($Account in $Resetpassword) {
        Set-ADAccountPassword  $Account -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Qwerty19" -force) -Reset
}
```

Results of 1 of the accounts:

> Set-ADAccountPassword : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot
>   convert the "@{sAMAccountName=math5-3}" value of type
>   "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type
>   "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount". At line:2 char:30
>   +         Set-ADAccountPassword <<<<  $Account -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Qwerty19" -force) -Re set
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADAccountPassword], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADAccoun
>   tPassword

Comment: Your `foreach` loop contains `$account.SamAccountName` . Does this bring back the username you're expecting to see? Identity eq $null means that's the missing bit

Comment: If your CSV contains just account names, drop ...Samaccount name and just use `$account`. like `foreach ( $account in $resetpasswords ) { Set-adAccountPassword $account -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Qwerty10" -force) -Reset }`

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, I tried it out. Once I removed the SamAccountName parts it gave a new error but seems to now be going through the .csv file. The error is "Cannot bind parameter "Identity". Cannot convert the "@(sAMAccountName=USERNAME)" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" To type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADAccountPassword" If I read this error right I can't convert the AD username to the custom object that I have created in this script?

Comment: I was also thinking maybe I am not properly using the -Identity in Set-AdAccountPassword

Comment: God knows. Any chance you can edit your post to include the results of this? `$resetpassword[1]`. Feel free to change anything identifiable, it's the variable names I'm looking for.

Comment: Sure thing. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah sorry, it's just `$resetpassword[1]` I'm after. It should bring back a table. The error suggests it's the CSV file that's the problem so `$resetpassword[1]` will show us the second line of the CSV in all its glory

Comment: Oh gotcha. It brings back 1 username, Math1-10. There are 225 total usernames in the .csv file.

Comment: Just the username and nothing else? In which case I can't see anything wrong. The problem is definitely the username, and you can prove this by changing the `set-adAccountpassword` to `get-aduser $account`. You should have the same kind of problems. What you could do is perhaps `foreach ( $account in $resetpassword ) { Set-AdAccountPassword $( [string]$account -replace " " ) -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Qwerty10" -force) -Reset }`

Comment: NOTE: in my first suggestion I used `$resetpasswords` and not `$resetpassword`. If you copied and pasted that would definitely be a problem since that variable wouldn't exist. Remove the s from `$resetpasswords`. Sorry for the typo!!!

Comment: No worries. You are right, it is the username. I tried that and got another error. "Cannot find an object with identity: '@(sAMAccountName=Math9-9)' under DC=domain, DC=org" These users definitely exist in this domain though. I'm wondering if maybe it would be easier to just create the users all over again instead of resetting their passwords at this point... I thought the .csv would basically be brought into powershell sort of like an array and the script would simply step through that one account by one.

Comment: `@(sAMAccountName=Math9-9)` means you have an object with property sAMAccountName and a value of Math9-9. That means you need to access that property in order to get the value, i.e. `$account.sAMAccountName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example 1 (CSV File Contains Header SamAccountName):**

Let's assume that `2019StudentsB115.csv` contains the following:

```
SamAccountName
Math9-9
Math1-1
User3
```

The following code should work:

```
$Accounts = Import-Csv "c:\2019StudentsB115.csv"
foreach ($Account in $Accounts) {
    Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $Account.SamAccountName -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Qwerty19" -AsPlainText -force) -Reset
}
```

**Example 2 (CSV File Contains No Headers):**

If your CSV file does not contain headers and you do not want to use headers, then do not use `Import-Csv`. `Get-Content` works well for a text file with single values on each line. Let's assume `2019StudentsB115.csv` contains the following:

```
Math9-9
Math1-1
User3
```

Here the CSV file contains no header. Now we can skip using `Import-Csv` for simplistic purposes. The code becomes the following and notice how the `.SamAccountName` property is no longer needed.

```
$Accounts = Get-Content "c:\2019StudentsB115.csv"
foreach ($Account in $Accounts) {
    Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $Account -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Qwerty19" -AsPlainText -force) -Reset
}
```

**Explanation:**

If you have a file that you read with `Import-Csv`, it will assume the very first row contains headers rather than values. The exception to this is if you use the `-Header` switch, which will automatically create a headers for you and consider the file contents to be all values.

When `Import-Csv` is used, the resulting object is an array of objects where each object contains a property for each header. In PowerShell to retrieve the value of a single property, you need to access that property directly. One such way is to use the syntax `object.property`. If you access the property from an object array, it will return the value of that property for every object in the array. That's where the `foreach` loop helps because it will iterate over every object in the array. In my example, `$Accounts` is the object array. `$Account` is the current iterated object, which has the property `SamAccountName` because of how the CSV file is constructed. The good thing about `Import-Csv` is that you can have many columns and headers in your file and you can choose to ignore or select ones that are useful.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment. Your explanation makes a lot of sense. The code did work wow thank you! So I wasn't wrong with the Set-AdAccountPassword portion. The object seemed to be right $Account.SamAccountName I thought I had to sort of 'bind' that object SamAccountName with the values stored in the array but I wasn't really sure how to do that. So you imported the .csv and assigned it it's own array object in one step instead of my original code where this was separated and some of the objects were defined within the loop vs. outside the loop. THANK YOU!